# Array with similar value being removed

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Basically, I've list of associative array and I'm trying to output both key and value for all. Here's the code I have.

```
$sites = array("www.google.com" => "Google", "www.apple.com" => "Apple", 
"www.apple.com" => "Apple");
foreach ($sites as $url => $name ){
echo $name . " " . $url . "<br/>"; 
}
```

As you can see 'apple' is being repeated and hence it's not being displayed in foreach loop. Here's the output of code above.

```
Google www.google.com
Apple www.apple.com
```

How to display all array values?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have 2 values in an associate array with the same index.

Comment: Make Array of Array

Comment: You can use simple array_unique() function to remove duplicate values.

Comment: @catcon Thanks. This fixed it.

Comment: I have added my answer with the use of array_unique()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Construct multidimensional array as follows. Because your array has duplicate indexes.
$sites = [
            ["www.google.com" => "Google"], 
            ["www.apple.com" => "Apple"], 
            ["www.apple.com" => "Apple"]
         ];

 foreach ($sites as $url_arr ){
      foreach ($url_arr as $url => $name ){
          echo $name . " " . $url . "<br/>"; 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Index cannot be the same ,hope this helps

```
$sites = array(array("www.google.com" => "Google"),array( "www.apple.com" => "Apple"), 
    array("www.apple.com" => "Apple"));
    foreach ($sites as $key => $value ){

      foreach($sites[$key] as $key1 =>$value1)
        {

          echo $sites[$key][$key1] . " " . $key1 . "<br/>"; 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any for loop.

You just need to use **`array_unique()**` function to remove duplicate values.

```
<?php

$sites = array("www.google.com" => "Google", "www.apple.com" => "Apple", 
"www.apple.com" => "Apple");

print_r(array_unique($sites));
?>
```

> **Output will  be like following**

```
Array ( [www.google.com] => Google [www.apple.com] => Apple )
```

Comment: He wanted to display all values.